# Is there any reason why I can't run an audio with crontab?

Tags: cron, audio, manjaro

I wanted to create a "radio alarm clock" with an old notebook. The first step was to have it play audio at a specific time, so I created this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "ideas for practice"
PATH=/home/rick/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
mpg123 -v /home/rick/Music/mala.mp3
```

And then added it to my crontab:
`* * * * * ./musicCron.sh 2>> ~/cron.log`

However, I always get the error:
`./musicCron.sh: line 6: 9803 Segmentation fault (core dumped) mpg123 -v ~/Music/mala.mp3`
i have try with ffplay too, so I think that the problem is not that.

Is there any reason why I can't execute mpg123 through crontab?

do you have other way to do that I want?
I don`t need to do that with cron.
There is another way?

Comment: You'd have to take a look at the coredump... could be circumstantial (something in the environment or missing from it triggers it) or some other limitation... you could also try another app like mpv, ffplay, sox-play, ... surely there are plenty of options?

Comment: also things like pulseaudio might only run if the user is logged in and active, and require environments to be set up, i.e. "permissions to play audio" in the widest sense can also be an issue

Comment: The entire thing appears to be a mess...